# How to Call a method in New version of app?

Tags: ios, iphone, default

i have few line code  which only called once at first time of app launch in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method,but now the problem is i need to called that part of code in new version of app because i made some changes there.as we know defaults are not deleted on updation so which way will be better to fix it.here is my code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
if(![fn chkAppRunningFirstTime])
    {
        [fn createFolder:@"productImages"];
        [fn addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:@"productImages"];
        [fn createFolder:@"productImages/thumb"];
        [fn createFolder:@"productImages/medium"];
        [fn createFolder:@"productImages/large"];

        [db executeQuery:"drop table productImgTbl;"];
        [db executeQuery:"create table productImgTbl ('no' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'img_name' text, 'img_url' text);"];
}
return YES;
}
```

fn is my Function Class where i am saving value like this way.

```
- (BOOL)chkAppRunningFirstTime
{
    return [defaults boolForKey:@"firstTime"];
}

- (void)setFirstTime:(BOOL)val
{
    [defaults setBool:val forKey:@"firstTime"]; 
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Any kind of suggestion will be appriacted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me your logic is a little backwards.

```
- (BOOL)chkAppRunningFirstTime
{
    return [defaults boolForKey:@"firstTime"];
}
```

This method returns the logically opposite value to the method name. When it is the first time it returns `NO`...

```
- (void)setFirstTime:(BOOL)val
{
    [defaults setBool:val forKey:@"firstTime"]; 
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

This method shouldn't take a parameter. It can only be the first time once so setting the flag always has the same value.

As the logic is backwards, you would be better to change the name of the key used, for example to `initialisationHasExecuted`.

The only other thing to consider is version number. Will you need to run other update code in future versions? How should that be handled in relation to this?

Comment: no i am changing the code in this version.i don't have plain to change the code in future version.

Comment: You need to consider all upgrade paths though. Compare people who are installing the app for the first time and people who are upgrading from your current (or an older) version.

Comment: but the second thing about parameter i am sure it is taking paramter because i am assigning it like this way [fn setFirstTime:YES]; .

Comment: Can you please explain your above comments through code because i am so conscious about this.Already i have receive so many complains of my app users thats why i am not in the position to take risk .

Comment: Each time you release the app the version number changes. You can store that as the value in user defaults. Then check if the number has changed. You can also have a method which checks the last version that was installed and runs an upgrade method for each released version number. So you don't remove any upgrade code, you just keep adding to it and checking which should be run.

Comment: I need to run update part of code only in next version for that i have written some code please conferm it.http://pastebin.com/7wxUUF4d it will works or not.i will be very thankful to you.

Comment: The version numbers aren't ints, they're floats. You can run tests by installing the app then changing the version number and running again. Add logging or debug to check what happens.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can store the previous version number in your app. Technically, you save the current versionNumber of your app (you can get it from the info-plist) for the key previous version. Then you can check on first launch whether the previous version matches the current version. If it does not match, you know you are an new version. Update the previous Version key in Userdefaults with the current version, done.